# PHP URL encoding issues

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, urlencode

I am working in wordpress and i have to set external products link which contains title as parameter to woocommerce product. all of the task is done but product title containts French words(â, ê, î, ô, û) so url is generating in wrong manner.

**Issue** : [http://antiqbook.com/search.php?action=search&owner_id=cab&title=Prom%C3%A9th%C3%A9e+et+Epim%C3%A9th%C3%A9e.](https://www.antiqbook.com/search.php?action=search&owner_id=cab&title=Prom%C3%A9th%C3%A9e%20et%20Epim%C3%A9th%C3%A9e.)

[**need**](https://www.antiqbook.com/search.php?action=search&owner_id=cab&title=Prom%EF%BF%BDth%EF%BF%BDe%20et%20Epim%EF%BF%BDth%EF%BF%BDe.) : http://antiqbook.com/search.php?action=search&owner_id=cab&title=Prom%E9th%E9e+et+Epim%E9th%E9e.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
    $url = "http://antiqbook.com/search.php? action=search&owner_id=cab&title=";
    $encodeUrl = urlencode("Prom%C3%A9th%C3%A9e+et+Epim%C3%A9th%C3%A9e.");
    $url .= $encodeUrl;
    echo $url; 
?>
```

Comment: You can use to above code, it might resolve your issue